# Combobox is not applied on the selectbox

Tags: jquery, combobox

I am working on combobox and new to it. I have created a simple selectbox and applied a combobox meth to it. I have included the necessary files but I am getting an error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'combobox'
```

Here is link to the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fPH2/)

Can any one guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: is there any combobox() method in jquery?

Comment: what u want to do explain that?

Comment: i was actually following this tutorial. http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combobox.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add resources for easyui

see resources tab on left

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/6fPH2/1/

```
jquery.easyui.min.js 
main.css 
easyui.css
```

Comment: Thanks @dev but I am confused how come jqueryui automation is using combobox method with out easy ui http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Actually the jquery autocomplete is different than what jquery easy ui is doing. If you not want to use the easy ui you should follow method that core jquery offeres. See the  view source of that page you will find a long configuration with <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  } .......

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the `jQuery EasyUI` in your script tag
As you are using the `jQuery EasyUI` plugings .You need to add the path of this plugin in your script tag.

see like this:

```
 <script src="myproject/scripts/jQuery EasyUI.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Somnath but I am confused how come jqueryui automation is using combobox method with out easy ui http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: i think there is no need to explain u dev as explained it